# Same number different formats in PHP

Tags: php

I have two numbers in PHP. 81.0000 and 81. While they are equal in reality I cannot get them to be equal in PHP.

I have tried casting both numbers to float and they still won't come thought as equal.

Anyone have any idea how I can have these two numbers be the same?

Comment: Can you include some example code?
`php > echo 81.0000 == 81;` returns true for me

Comment: Are u using `===` for checking??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the awesome [WARNING](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) on php.net:

> never trust floating number results to the last digit, and never compare floating point numbers for equality.

The very best you can to is type cast to `(int)`, or use PHP rounding functions like [`round()`](http://php.net/round), [`floor()`](http://php.net/floor), or [`ceil()`](http://php.net/ceil).

**UPDATE**
Check out the [Arbitrary Precision Math Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) such as the one @Jose Vega pointed out in his answer.  They should get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 3):

[bccomp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php) — Compare two arbitrary precision numbers

```
bccomp ( string $left_operand , string $right_operand [, int $scale ] )

<?php

echo bccomp('1', '2') . "\n";   // -1
echo bccomp('1.00001', '1', 3); // 0
echo bccomp('1.00001', '1', 5); // 1

?>
```